# Packet drop function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to code a function which can simulate the packet drop any percentage of the packets in Python. I am using scapy for this. But I am unable to get any result while pinging 8.8.8.8 as no packet loss is happening. Can someone guide me on this on how to improve this function so that it can simulate packet dropping? I am attaching the code below:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP
import random

def drop_packets(probability):
    def process_packet(packet):
        if random.random() < probability:
            # Dropping the packet
            return 
        elif packet.haslayer(IP) and (packet[IP].src == "8.8.8.8" or packet[IP].dst == "8.8.8.8"):
            return
        else:
            
            send(packet)

 
    sniff(prn=process_packet, filter="", store=0)


drop_packets(0.9)
```

There is no result on pinging 8.8.8.8. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you intend your function to do in the case of "packet drop"?

Comment: I want my function to drop network packets. For example, I want to drop the packets while pinging 8.8.8.8 by 90% using this function. I am trying to simulate the packet drop function in real-life scenario.

Comment: And what is the function currently doing with the packet instead of dropping it?

Comment: It is sending all the packets without dropping them.

Comment: So you mean that both `random.random() < probability` and `packet.haslayer(IP) and (packet[IP].src == "8.8.8.8" or packet[IP].dst == "8.8.8.8")` were false? Have you checked if any of these conditions is ever true?

Comment: Yes, I've checked. These conditions are true.

Comment: What happens if you replace the entire function body of `process_packet` by a single `return` statement?

Comment: Let me try it once.

Comment: If you ping 8.8.8.8, the ICMP packet will be sent by your OS anyway.  Scapy cannot prevent the OS from sending a packet.

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out. Thank you for helping me.